# Unable to retrieve JSON file in Angular 2 project

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular2-services

I am trying to display static JSON data in my angular 2 project. I am getting a console error 'GET http://localhost:4200/app/data/MOCK_DATA.json 404 (Not Found)' I have added my services.ts and component.ts pages.

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ConfigurationService } from '../../configuration.service';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ListItem } from './list-item';


@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(
    private _http: Http,
    private _configurationService: ConfigurationService
  ) {}

 get() : Observable<ListItem[]> {
      return this._http.get("app/data/MOCK_DATA.json")
      .map((response: Response) => <ListItem[]> response.json())

  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { ListItem } from './list-item';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: 'component.html',
  styleUrls: ['component.css']
})
export class Component implements OnInit {


  busy:Subscription;
  datas: ListItem[] = [];


  constructor(
    private _dataService: DataService,
    private _confirmationService: ConfirmationService,
    private _authService: AuthService,
    private _router: Router,
  ) { 


  }

  ngOnInit(){

  }
getdatas() {
    this.busy =
      this._dataService.get()
        .subscribe(data => this.datas = data)
  }
```

Comment: I redirects me to another page

Comment: If you are using angular-cli, you need to add it to your assets folder and do the http request to that folder.

Comment: angular cli only allows json from the assets folder?...and yes I am using angular cli

Comment: @userlkjsflkdsvm Well once in prod environment, angular-cli bundles up your files into a dist folder so your paths are changing. That's why you should put your static files into the assets folder.

Comment: the path may be wrong, try removing the `app`,  `this._http.get("data/MOCK_DATA.json")` or try relative path 'like `this._http.get("../../data/MOCK_DATA.json")` depending on your folder structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is static. there is no need to `http.get`.

Create a `json.ts` file

export your JSON file as

```
export const json={
    "key":"value"
}
```

then import it where required

`import { json } from './json.ts'`

then `console.log(json)` inside the class to check the file/json.